# Simplification of series

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, contest-math

> $$S=\frac{(10!+9!)(8!+7!)(6!+5!)(4!+3!)(2!+1!)}{(10!-9!)(8!-7!)(6!-5!)(4!-3!)(2!-1!)}$$

One way to solve this might be by taking out a common factor but I do not think what might be the common factor.

I tried using a calculator and the answer comes out to be $11$

But obviously using a calculator is cheating

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is $n$ used? Do you mean sequence rather than series?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews See the edit

Answer (score 6):

Let's consider
$$\frac{(n+1)!+n!}{(n+1)!-n!}.$$
As $(n+1)!=n!(n+1)$, cancelling $n!$ gives
$$\frac{(n+1)+1}{(n+1)-1}=\frac{n+2}n.$$

Answer (score 5):

Since $10! = 10 \cdot 9!$, $(10! + 9!)= (10+1)9!$ and $(10! - 9!) = (10-1)9!$.  Apply the same reasoning to each of the other factors.  All the factorials we have factored from the terms cancel...

Answer (score 4):

Divide the top and bottom of $\dfrac{10! + 9!}{10!-9!}$ by $9!$ to get $11/9$. Then divide the top and bottom of the next term by $7!$ to get $9/7$.  Keep on going, and you'll arrive at $11$ after cancelling.